# Git ignore changes to file but keep it in the repo

Tags: c#, git, ignore

This is a git question concerning our C# Xamarin project.

We have a couple files in an Assets folder that are copied in there by a pre-build event command.  The files are not used directly by the compiler but if they are missing our CI server will fail the build.  The versions of them that are on all the dev machines are probably different so whenever we build on our machines the files get copied in and git shows that they are **changed**

It's annoying because changes to these files really don't matter so we never need to commit them.  I want to ignore changes to these files but not remove them from the repo.  If they are removed as mentioned above CI will fail.  If I straight up "remove and stop tracking" them they will be deleted from the CI server when it pulls.

From other stack overflow questions I have tried both of these:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged [path]
git update-index --skip-worktree [path]
```

Both succeed in hiding the file changes but both present the following problem.  When I try to switch branches it tells me I must discard unstaged changes before switching and lists those files.  I then type:

```
git reset -- .
git checkout .
```

Both fail to discard the changes to the files until I reverse the update-index commands, only then can I discard the changes and be allowed to switch branches.

Is there a solution to this?  Are we doing something outside the box or just plain wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common problem.

Sometimes it's the well known `custom.js`, `custom.min.js`, `custom.css`, `custom.min.css`, and the likes.  Other times it's another kind of "source files" that somehow needs to be "there" in order for software to work, but we dont really care about what's in them.

Sounds familiar? It's called compiled files. Now I know they are not *actually* compiled files - they are source files. But for all intents and puposes these files are pretty much the same as compiled files. They are not really anything you care about, and would rather the computer just figured out how to maintain them.

Why treat them any different, than actual compiled files? You mention a pre-build event command makes these files every time you build. That practically makes them part of the build process.

The solution is rather straightforward. On the CI server include the pre-build event that generates the files, before the actual compiling, and add the files to the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: What you are describing is exactly the problem we are having.  But when we tried simply adding them to the .gitignore file git would delete the file when the build server pulled and then the build would fail.

Comment: Here is your problem: _when the build server pulled the build would fail_.

In order for this to work the build server must be able to generate these files. You have to make it part of the build process to generate these files - before compiling.

Comment: So, the more I delve back into this the more I remember about what went wrong the first time.  We had the pre-build event copy the files from where they are on the build server but of course on the dev machines they are in a different location.  So if the file goes missing on a dev machine then it wont be copied back and pre-build returns an error and build failes.  But i can probably find some work around for that so that we aren't pestered by it during development.  I didn't think that a straightforward ignore would be the solution but it was.  I'll mark your answer as solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Glad I could help.